# Is there a way to shrink particles to mesh surface?

Tags: physics, particles

I attempted to create a dripping effect like this:

[image]

On a curved surface using [this technique](http://www.blenderguru.com/videos/how-to-make-a-rainy-window/), however the long particles don't conform to the surface, looking very unrealistic (it looks particularly bad on sharp corners).

Is there another way to get this effect, or a way to use this technique on a curved surface?

In other words, I want to make the particles stick to the surface (while still being able to slide freely) and somehow leave trails behind them.

---

*Image from [Blender Guru](http://www.blenderguru.com/videos/how-to-make-a-rainy-window/)*

Comment: As I recall he manually made a few drops and used a particle system to distribute them. For a still that would mean apply particle system and sculpt the drops to the uneven surface.

Comment: @sambler Is there a way to snap to the surface automatically? (shrinkwrap?) Sculpting each one seems incredibly tedious..

Comment: I can't think of a way to make it work automatically. Shrinkwrap would pull the entire droplet flat, vert groups would pull the back and leave the top way out. shrinkwrap a flat piece to the surface and then displacing would not create good looking drops. None of these help with a particle system, only after it was applied. Either sculpt or proportional edit in edit mode to an applied particle system is all I can think of. What we want is a shnkwrap that has a preserve volume option, allowing the closest edge to shrink down but still prevent the other sides from collapsing.

Comment: @sambler I guess in that case I will just try and sculpt the drops from scratch.. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Sardi Pax released a tutorial for applying metaball particles as raindrops to glass, I believe there is no reason that prevents his method from being applied to a curved surface.
If this method is used instead of sculpted particles, they should conform to a non planar surface.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RDte-IzvHlg

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged, please add some more information to your answer. (If the link goes, so does the answer) Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) Is there any way to make this have long drips like the image above?

Comment: If you wanna know more about the application, features, advantages, main components, working principles, and other ways, you are welcome to this [[page](https://www.allpackchina.com/the-definite-buying-guide-of-shrink-wrap-machine/)](https://www.allpackchina.com/the-definite-buying-guide-of-shrink-wrap-machine/) of allpackchina.